# Unexpected '+' Error. Expected ']' in accessing indices of an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have some php code where I look into a file, read till EOF then use a PHP script to insert them into a mysql database. Here's the code:

```
$array = array();
while(!feof($filehandle)) {
        $line = fgets($filehandle);
        array_push($array, $line);
}
$i = 0;
while($i < count($array)-1) {
        $insert = mysqli_query( $dbhandle, "INSERT INTO " . $table_name . "(column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('$array[$i]' , '$array[$i+1]', '$array[$i+2]')");
        $i += 3;
}
```

When I run this, it has an error at my `mysqli_query` line `syntax error, unexpected '+', expecting ']'`

I've tried to do string concatenation:
`'$array[$i]' ,'".$array[$i+1]." ,` 
and this runs without an error, but the data isn't popping up in my db.

As a temp solution, I have `$j = $i + 1` and `$k = $i + 1` which i use to index my array, and seems to work fine...

Any idea what is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP will not allow you  to evaluate an expression like that in a double quoted string, unless you wrap it in `{}` as `'{$array[$i+2]}'`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBerkowski.that worked well.

Comment: Any inputs on how I can make my question better? I thought this was a legitimate question, but maybe to PHP developers this is too novice to be in SO?

Comment: you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are simply assuming the query could never fail.

Comment: Questions related to syntax problems are often not well received, but -3 is a little excessive for this one. You didn't just come here to say "why doesn't this work?" - you took steps to isolate the problem and attempt alternate solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use expressions inside strings like regular variables and arrays.

This is okay:

```
echo "$arr[0]";
```

This is not:

```
echo "$arr[$i+1]";
echo "strtolower('test')";
echo "1+1"; // would output "1+1" and not "2"
```

You want to enclose the array inside curly braces:

```
echo "${arr[$i+1]}"; // outputs the correct result
echo "{$arr[$i+1]}"; // outputs the correct result
```

This only works for variables:

```
echo "${myVar}"; // ok
echo "{strtolower('test')}"; // won't work
```

Also, as @MarcinNabialek said, I think you need to change your while:

```
while($i < count($array)-3) {
```

Comment: But confusingly, it _does_ work in an array key, as in `echo "{$array[strtolower('TEST')]}"` to access `$array['test']`

Comment: Yeah, it's a confusing standard. I guess you can use expressions where they can be explicitly defined to work. To avoid putting any random text inside curly braces, because that would cause issues: `"{doesntexist(1)}"` would be stupid if it works, but inside an array key, I guess it's almost okay. I wonder if `"${strtolower('Key')"` would output `$key`...